# Does "I should take an aspirin" have two meanings?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Mr. Swan in his book Oxford Grammar said that "if I were you" can be omitted when someone gives advice. For instance,

> I should take an aspirin.

would mean

> I suggest you take an aspirin.

Suppose someone tells me that they have a headache and I say this, wouldn't it mean that I myself really should take an aspirin because perhaps they might think that I have a headache too?

Comment: No, you may safely assume that they would not think that, not unless you are so distressed by the other person's headache that you feel in need medication yourself.

Comment: Note that there's also likely to be some difference in the intonation, between making a suggestion adn commenting about your own state.

Comment: "I should take an aspirin" does not mean "I suggest you take an aspirin" in AmE (or at least it's extremely rare). We'd be more likely to say "I would take an aspirin".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I suspect that is true in BrE as well.